# Why is Require_Once not finding a file that exists on disk

Tags: php, require, relative-path, chdir

I have the following code

```
    require_once  "../pages/appconfig.php";
  require_once "../freezer/data_functions.php";
```

Starting yesterday I'm getting the following error on the second file

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

for both of these files.  It has been working up until today.

```
echo realpath("../freezer/data_functions.php");
```

I get the correct full file path of the file that exists on disk.

I made a bunch of changes to other files but none that should affect these calls.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Using absolute paths, or using relative paths with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, will eliminate this type of issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that as part of the appconfig.php includes I was calling a function that called

```
        chdir(__DIR__ . "\\..\\");
```

and even though I changed it back again, I still got these odd issues.  Removed the call to chdir and problem solved.